# How to do a pause in C# for Windows Phone 8 using Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to do a pause upon clicking on btnPause. The OnUpdate enables the ball to move around the screen. Now, I want to pause the moving by clicking on btnPause. So that, I could resume it later on. I have no idea on how to do about it. I hope anyone of you could guide me. The codes that I have are as below.

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
    {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this.GreenBall1, this.greenBallVelocityX + Canvas.GetLeft(this.GreenBall1));
            Canvas.SetTop(this.GreenBall1, this.greenBallVelocityY + Canvas.GetTop(this.GreenBall1));

            var greenBallPositionX1 = Canvas.GetLeft(this.GreenBall1);
            var greenBallPositionY1 = Canvas.GetTop(this.GreenBall1);

            var maximumGreenBallX = ActualWidth - this.GreenBall1.ActualWidth;
            var maximumGreenBallY = 400 - this.GreenBall1.ActualHeight; //Improvise: Instead of 360, get maximum height of canvas

            if (greenBallPositionX1 > maximumGreenBallX || greenBallPositionX1 < 0)
            {
                this.greenBallVelocityX *= -1;
            }

            if (greenBallPositionY1 > maximumGreenBallY || greenBallPositionY1 < 0)
            {
                this.greenBallVelocityY *= -1;
            }
         }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried to do to get this to work? In this case I would do:

```
private bool _paused = false;

private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
{
    if (_paused)
    {
       return;
    }
    ...
}

private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _paused != _paused;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oren, I have tried to do an if-else statement for OnUpdate. However, it did not work. I have tried your given codes too. But, it is not working.

Comment: This is what I did var btn = sender as Button; if (btn != null) in OnUpdate.

Comment: `OnUpdate` should never be called by the button though, right? What's triggering `OnUpdate`? What do you mean "doesn't work"? If it doesn't work then you're not triggering the `DateTime` correctly, or you put my code in the wrong place (i.e. there is somewhere else that is also drawing). Note that my code only pauses for 1/2 a second.

Comment: It did not pause. And also, I believe that there is an error regarding DateTime.Minimum. The error is System.DateTime does not contain a definition for Minimum. Therefore, I changed it to MinValue. But, it is not working neither.

Comment: I am sorry as I am pretty poor in C# programming.

Comment: Good point about `MinValue`, updated. Did you add my `if` code at the start? If you change `AddMilliseconds` to add 10000 and set a breakpoint in your drawing code what do you see?

Comment: I am sorry, I have put the if statement in the wrong position. It is working now. I would like to know if there is any way that I do not need to use time? Because I would like to pause the moving and resume it by clicking on another button such as btnResume.

Comment: updated. Now when you hit the button it will toggle pause / play. If you want to have separate buttons just have one button do `_paused = true` and the other `_paused = false`

Comment: I got it now. Thank you very much!